# how to add the UITableView detailDisclosurebutton custom in ipad app

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I have tableView with detailDisclosure button it works fine but i want to give title to detail disclosure button so i think i need to add custom  UIButton for detailDisclosure is it possible to do like i want to do this without using custom cell.

If i want to give image it works fine but how may i give title to this button like comment.

```
  cell.accessoryView = [[ UIImageView alloc ] 
                            initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loginN.png" ]];
```

Comment: You can add UIButton as subview to cell.

Comment: @HRM can you please help me out how to do this and how will it call the things which we call when cell is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
UIButton *btn = [[[UIButton alloc]init]autoerelease];
btn .frame = CGRectMake(210.0, 0.0, 90, 25);
btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loginN.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClickHandler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubView: btn];
```

and in btnClickHandler do this to get indexPath

```
- (void)btnClickHandler :(UIButton *)button {

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
//Get your data source object from indexPath.row.
}
```

Comment: when i click this is it possible to call- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 PostData*theCellData = [postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 postID=theCellData.postID;

Comment: You can get the indexPath on button click event like this UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

Answer (score 0):

Why don't u set the a button as accessory view just like u try setting an image..??

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 80.0, 80.0);//Set the frame u need for the view

    //Customize the button
    [button setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //And set it as accessory view
    cell.accessoryView = button;
```

Here is the result... 
[image]

Comment: Well, it should... what do u mean by it didn't work..?? Can u post ur code..??

Comment: @JanDeveloper , I edited the code and added the screenshot.. try..:)

Comment: thanks for the help i got the above answers working also and your code i can only accept one question i am upvoting your question thanks